# Backbone model property getting updated on update of another property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

Here is my model:

```
var SendAlertsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults: {
                customSubject: "",
                customNote: "",
                userList:[],
                alertUserList:[]
            }

        });
```

Inside view:

```
initialize: function(options) {
                var self= this;
                if(_.isUndefined(options)===false){
                    self.model= new SendAlertsModel();
                    self.loggedInUser = app.user;
                    self.model.set("userList",options.previousTabData.get("userList"));
                    self.model.set("alertUserList",options.previousTabData.get("userList"));
                    self.model.get("alertUserList").push(self.loggedInUser);
                }
            },
```

The issue which i am facing here is when i push the loggedInUser to alertUserList array, it automatically pushes the same loggedInUser to userList array.

Please give your suggestions on this.

Thanks

Comment: @nikoshr Could you please share the appropriate link ? Thanks

Comment: I closed your question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/34951015/1071630 but that was probably a mistake

Comment: Thanks.. Not an issue

Comment: I don't think you need the var self = this; in this case as you haven't changed context within the if block.

Comment: But that should not be a problem @Rupert

Comment: Is it something because of reading the values from the same list in both the properties ?

Comment: @Yameen I know, just tidying up the code ;)

Comment: @Rupert Thanks for that .. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
//create new alerts model
model = new SendAlertsModel();

//assign logged in user to local variable
loggedInUser = app.user;

//set the user list to be the user list from the previous tab data
model.set("userList",options.previousTabData.get("userList"));  

//set the alertUserList to be the previous tab user list by reference
model.set("alertUserList",options.previousTabData.get("userList"));

//push the logged in user into the alert user list
model.get("alertUserList").push(self.loggedInUser);
```

I think the issue occurs when you set the **alertUserList** to be the **userList**. As the user list is an object the **alertUserList** now contains a reference to the userList. It's not a copy. When you update the **alertUserList** you are actually updating the **userList** too.

Think of it like this:

```
var alertUserList = userList = {some object in memory};
```

In this line here you will want to create a copy rather:

```
model.set("alertUserList",options.previousTabData.get("userList"));
```

I'm not sure of what data type userList is, so it will depend on that. If you only need a shallow copy then you could do this using your underscore/lodash library (I assume that is what the "_" is):

```
model.set("alertUserList",_.clone(options.previousTabData.get("userList")));
```

Comment: userList is the list of users comming from the previous tab. And i need to show the loggedin user also. So i am creating a new property in model named alertUserList where i push the loggedinuser to show on grid. But i need the original userList also. So i am saving it in userList. And yes you are right, i am just creating the references here and thats why its updating the userList property also

Comment: Perhaps create a property on your model called "userList" for the original list and put a clone in the "alertUserList" property.

Comment: I did clone, but its adding lot of unwanted attributes. is there any way of keeping only the original attributes ?

Comment: You could use the pick method from underscore: http://underscorejs.org/#pick and specify the attributes you want.

Comment: Replacing `defaults` with a function would also be a good idea, including mutable values (such as arrays) in the defaults is just asking for trouble.